# Prevent user changing ID in URL to see other records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

You may have seen the news story about HotelHippo leaking data. Essentially once logged in you can change the five-digit ID number in the URL and see other bookings on the system.
For me, I code websites in MVC and so I'm used to the {controller}/{action}/{id} look of the URL.
[bbc news](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-28107277) - [Scott Helme](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hotel-hippo-insecure/)

My question is this: with MVC how can you prevent changing the URL showing other users' data? Is there an "accepted" way / best practice?

I can think of a couple:

- Build a security module that checks the record in the database when accessed for permissions
- Change the routing so the user never sees the ID in the url (though IDs still used when you click a link and pass it to the action... how?)
- Simply don't use sequential IDs (but isn't this security through obscurity and not to be solely relied upon?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing Url manipulation attacks with MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741653/preventing-url-manipulation-attacks-with-mvc)

Comment: Things may have moved on in the 5 years since that question - MVC certainly has.

Comment: Use POST if you have this kind of scenario.

Comment: I answered something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207636/do-i-need-to-use-validateantiforgerytoken-and-html-antiforgerytoken-on-al/17208513#17208513 having developed in mvc for a while now, i always pass the user id from a source that isn't easily modified, encrypted auth cookie or something similar, then use that when selecting any data out, if it doesn't match the users range of data, then throw an error and show a nice page.

Comment: @Slicksim "if it doesn't match the users range of data" - this would come under the security module idea above (whether the code is in a stored procedure or in the service layer). What about "lighter" methods (if the data wasn't that important, or the DB could not be changed say) - how else can we prevent users jumping around?

Answer (score -1):

A bit late, but well here is my answer =D

You can work with a token (at least thats how i do it ^^):

**Token.php**

```
class Token {

    //generate the token name
    public static function generate(){

        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));

    }//end generate()

    //chek token is correct
    public static function check($token){

        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        //check if session exists and if token supplied is equal to the one given to the user
        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)){

            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;

        }//end if exists

        return false;

    }//end check()

}//end class Token
```

**Input.php**

```
//with this class, we catch the input of the user

class Input {

//check if data exists in post or get
public  static function exists($type = 'post'){

    switch($type){

        case 'post':
                return(!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
            break;

        case 'get':
                return(!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
            break;

        default:
                return false;
            break;

    }//end switch $type

}//end exists

//get selected $item
public static function  get($item){

    if(isset($_POST[$item])){

        return $_POST[$item];

    }else if (isset($_GET[$item])){

        return $_GET[$item];

    }//end if else

    return '';

}//end get

}//end class
```

**HTML**

On your HTML site that will redirect to the next page with the ID:

Create a form with input fileds

```
<!-- Form comes here -->

<!--add a token to the form(security, so you cant edit the url)-->
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php ECHO Token::generate(); ?>">
```

Check the token on submit of the form

```
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
//do your redirect and other stuff here
}
```

With this, you should be able to make it imosible for a user to change the URL. You can then redirect to a frobidden site afetr the "If token exists" check.

I hope it helps you ^^

Answer (score -3):

You can Guid instead of integers as the ID of your entities

Comment: But it is still possible (though unlikely) to guess another valid GUID. In HotelHippo's case, if they had used a GUID users could still access other customers' data.

Comment: Guid is harder to guess but if guessed can still be used to manipulate other user's records. This is security by obscurity and is not safe at all.